# Advantages and disadvantages of using classification tree

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-trees

I was working on a project and was trying to validate my decisions. I wondered why would I want to use a decision tree over more powerful algorithms like random forest or Gradient boosting machine which uses similar tree based architecture.

Comment: If you want to use one decision tree, you should compute the optimal decision tree (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGW0mygEW44)

Answer (score 0):

One main advantage of using Decision Tree is that you can visualize your prediction more precisely than any other classification approaches.

In addition,

- What rules make any specific prediction? You can generate such rules
- What feature/value is crucial for what decision? You can indirectly do the feature selection.

There are some shortcomings as well; sometimes, the tree might get quite large, so you have to reduce the size of the tree (pruning) with the cost of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Decision Tree has 2 key benefits over Random Forest:

- **Interpretability** – In many domain, this is a must.
- **Faster** prediction time – Can be an issue with RF (if n_estomators is too high) and when it has to be an online prediction.

*Unless you have these constraints*, RF is the go-to algorithm. For sparse and high-dimension data, SVM should also be tried.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages:-

1.) Faster than RF.

2.) Relatively easy to interpret than other algo's, although most of the
algorithms are interpretable more or less.

3.) Easy to visualize.

4.) Can have control over feature selection if you don't want to go over the
filter based or wrapper based feature selection.

5.) Easy to implement.

6.) Easy to tune the hyperparameters.

7.) Easy to prune.

But if you really want to get better results, either go for RF or with some Gradient Boosting algorithms.